# Turn off gravity when a user sends the application to the background

Tags: sprite-kit, appdelegate

I have a simple gravity related game in SpriteKit. Before the game starts gravity is off. When the screen is touched the following code is called:

```
missile?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

If you take a message and come back to it I would like gravity to switch off until you touch the screen again.

I'm guessing it is something in the AppDelegate, but I am literally stuck there.

Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: why do you want gravity turned off?  wouldn't you just want to pause the scene?

Comment: Pausing the scene is what I would like to do yes. What’s the best way to implement it?

Comment: set up a worldNode to hold all of your gamenodes (not your overlay pause menu), then use worldNode.isPaused = true.

Comment: Thanks. Will you call the pausing of worldNode from the app delegate for when it goes into the background?

Answer (score 0):

First add add an observer for `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` to your mainNode like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

now you can pause your mainNode in `appMoveToBackground`:

```
@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    mainNode.isPaused = true
}
```

Make sure to remove the observer in `deinit`:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```